# OpenVPN Connection without disabling Internet debugging

Tags: configuration, openvpn, remote, debugging, internet

I've recently configured OpenVPN on my server (CentOS 7) and been configuring it for hours now and everything seems to work fine except that when I connect using a client machine I cannot access the internet.

I know there are solutions on this site and I have read through many of them without any success although I have tried their suggested answers mainly the following server.conf settings.

```
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"
user nobody
group nobody
```

I also added the following iptables rules (I'm using iptables instead of firewalld)

```
# iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
# iptables -A INPUT -I eth0 -m state --state NEW -p udp --dport 1195 -j
```

As well as edited sysctl.conf to have

```
# net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

When I set up OpenVPN on CentOS 5 it worked perfectly and I didn't have this problem although it seems to be worrying me in CentOS 7

*NOTE*

I forgot to mention that this install of OpenVPN is running on port 1195, enabling port 1195 was not a typo

```
# iptables -L | grep policy

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
```

Windows Client ifconfig

```
Ethernet adapter Ethernet 2:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 4:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 5:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : Home
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::9175:325f:2c9f:3c45%8
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.20.4
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.20.1

Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::ecfb:cd4d:f388:1765%3
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.8.0.6
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.252
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

Tunnel adapter isatap.Home:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : Home

Tunnel adapter Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Tunnel adapter isatap.{6A60203F-046E-42E7-A865-37847D3036CA}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
```

Comment: iptables -L gives "Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT) Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT) Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)"

Comment: the port 1194 was a typo

Comment: Next questions please. 1. You're using `-A` to append rules to your `INPUT` and `POSTROUTING` chains. Are there any other rules in those chains or in `FORWARD` that explicitly deny traffic between your OpenVPN clients and the Internet? 2. From your client can you `ping` the non-VPN IP address of your server?

Comment: I can ssh to the OpenVPN servers IP address just fine once the connection has been made

Comment: the VPN address is 10.8.0.0 I can ssh to the servers address which is 192.168.20.40 if that's what you mean

Comment: Routing table on the _client_ please (after the VPN is established) showing all routes that involve the VPN tunnel. I'm expecting to see at least two entries.

Comment: Here you go, sorry it took so long

Comment: That's the output from `ipconfig`. I need to see the routing table please.

Comment: I don't know how to view the routing table on windows I only know Linux :'D